# Error adding item to comboBox javaFx FXML

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, combobox, fxml

Im trying to add all the items in an ArrayList to a javafx ComboBox but i keep getting a wierd error,

```
no suitable method found for add(String)
method Collection.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CAP#1)
method List.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CAP#1)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
  CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

## Java Code

```
File fJSon = new File("roomDetails.json"); 
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 try{

  Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("roomDetails.json"));
  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;


  List<String> itemIDS = new ArrayList<String> (jsonObject.keySet()); //gets json keys from a json oject previously defined
   for (int i = 0; i < itemIDS.size(); i++) {
            room_id.getItems().add(String.valueOf(i));
      }
```

## FXML file

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
 xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
 fx:controller="pp01_cwk03.AddStaffController">
     <children>
         <Pane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="428.0" 
                  prefWidth="593.0">
            <children>

                <ComboBox fx:id="room_id" layoutX="187.0" layoutY="178.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
             </children>
        </Pane>
       </children>
    </Pane>
</children>
```

## roomDetails.json

```
{"366O":
     ["Room Name:CEO",
      "Department Name:IT",
      "Occupant Name:Charindu",
      "Space Type:Office"],
"527F":
     ["Room Name:IT Lab",
      "Department Name:IT",
      "Occupant Name:Saman",
      "Space Type: Library"]
}
```

This code which gets the KEYS from the json oject works becouse i tested it my self with a for loop which prints the array details

```
 List<String> itemIDS = new ArrayList<String> (jsonObject.keySet());
```

**IN FACT**  When i even put,

```
room_id.getItems().add("Hello");
```

It still would show the same error, the problem some what seems to be with the comboBox i created from scenebuilder JavaFX

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `room_id.getItems().add(String.valueOf(i));` you should use `room_id.getItems().add(itemIDS.get(i));` that should solve the problem.

Can you show the Sample JSON?

Here is the working Sample Controller

```
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ComboTestController implements Initializable {

    Stage primaryStage;

    public ComboBox comboBox;

    /**
     * Called to initialize a controller after its root element has been
     * completely processed.
     *
     * @param location  The location used to resolve relative paths for the root object, or
     *                  <tt>null</tt> if the location is not known.
     * @param resources The resources used to localize the root object, or <tt>null</tt> if
     */
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.append("Key1", "Value 1");
        jsonObject.append("Key2", "Value 2");
        jsonObject.append("Key3", "Value 3");
        List<String> itemIDS = new ArrayList<String>(jsonObject.keySet()); //gets json keys from a json oject previously defined
        for (int i = 0; i < itemIDS.size(); i++) {
            comboBox.getItems().add(itemIDS.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }
}
```

And FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.AutoMaven.ui.controller.ComboTestController">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="185.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="260.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here sample screenshot

[image]

Comment: Still, i keep getting the same error :/

Comment: Don't use raw types.